# iPhone - ignoring the second touch on an area

Tags: iphone

I have a view that the users are allowed to finger paint. The code is working perfectly if the area is touched with one finger. For example: I touch it with one finger and move the finger. Then, a line is drawn as I move the first finger. If I touch with a second finger the same view, the line that was being drawn by the first finger stops.

I would like to ignore any touch beyond the first, i.e., to track the first touch but ignore all others to the same view.

I am using touchesBegan/moved/ended.

I have used this to detect the touches

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:myView];
```

I have also tried this

```
lastPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:myView];
```

but nothing changed.

How do I do that - track the first touch and ignore any subsequent touch to a view?

thanks.

NOTE: the view is NOT adjusted to detect multiple touches.

Comment: Wont `yourView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;` be enough

Comment: apparently not. I have multipleTouchEnabled = NO and the problem still happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A given touch will maintain the same memory address as long as it is in contact with the screen. This means you can save the address as an instance variable and ignore any events from other objects. However, do not retain the touch. If you do, a different address will be used and your code won't work.

Example:

Add `currentTouch` to your interface:

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
    UITouch *currentTouch;
    ...
}
...
@end
```

Modify `touchesBegan:` to ignore the touch if one is already being tracked:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(currentTouch) return;
    currentTouch = [touches anyObject];
    ...
}
```

Modify `touchesMoved:` to use `currentTouch` instead of getting a touch from the set:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(!currentTouch) return;
    CGPoint currentPoint = [currentTouch locationInView:myView];
    ...
}
```

Modify `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCancelled:` to clear `currentTouch`, but only if `currentTouch` has ended or been cancelled.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(currentTouch && currentTouch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded) {
        ...
        currentTouch = nil;
    }
}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(currentTouch && currentTouch.phase == UITouchPhaseCancelled) {
        ...
        currentTouch = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it!!!!!! Thanks. Using this method I solve two problems: the one stated by this question and a lag that was happening when I touched the view and started drawing. Now the drawing part is fast and ignoring any touch beyond the first. The only small glitch is that when I touch the second finger, the first one stops drawing.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

From the [reference documents on UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

> `multipleTouchEnabled`
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether
>   the receiver handles multitouch
>   events.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isMultipleTouchEnabled) BOOL
>   multipleTouchEnabled Discussion
>
> When set to YES, the receiver receives
>   all touches associated with a
>   multitouch sequence. When set to NO,
>   the receiver receives only the first
>   touch event in a multitouch sequence.
>   The default value of this property is
>   NO.
>
> Other views in the same window can
>   still receive touch events when this
>   property is NO. If you want this view
>   to handle multitouch events
>   exclusively, set the values of both
>   this property and the exclusiveTouch
>   property to YES.

Comment: thanks, but I have multipleTouchEnabled = NO and the problem is still happening.